# How make windows focus only in one monitor while the other is being used by another device?

Tags: multiple-monitors, hdmi, windows-11

I brought the LG 32gn600-b monitor and it has more than one video input. In the display port input I connected to my PC, in the HDMI input I connected to my Nintendo Switch.

In my setup I have a Samsung monitor with single input also connected to the PC.

The problem is that everytime that I change the video output in the LG monitor to the Nintendo switch, the windows still recognize the monitor as connected and keeps it as the main screen. So every time I change the display to the switch, I have to manually change to single screen.

Is there a way to make windows change to singlescreen (Using the Samsung monitor as main screen) when the LG monitor is displaying the nintendo Switch screen?

I'm using Windows 11.

Comment: Generally speaking, monitors don't use outputs, they have inputs. I still don't understand your setup. Which monitor is the PC going to.. both?

Comment: Thank you for commenting! My PC is connected in my samsung monitor and in my LG monitor that have displayport and HDMI input*, my nintendo switch is connected to my LG monitor as well. I want that when I change for the nintendo switch on my LG, the windows make it so the samsung monitor as my only screen. Today it keeps as "extended" screens

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since there is no handshake from your Switch to your PC, there is nothing telling the PC that the LG is being used by the Switch. That is to say, your computer isn't receiving any instructions to change the monitor setup just because you changed the input on the LG.

What you can do is to use a simple Windows utility called [displayswitch](https://ss64.com/nt/displayswitch.html) which allows you to send system commands to control which monitors are active. Here are some features:

Options

```
   /internal    Switch to use the primary display only.
   1            All other connected displays will be disabled. 

   /clone       The primary display will be mirrored on a second screen.
   2        

   /extend      Expand the Desktop to a secondary display.
   3            This allows one desktop to span multiple displays. (Default).

   /external    Switch to the external display only (second screen).
   4            The current main display will be disabled.
```

There is also a GUI if you aren't savy with command lines, but I recommend writing a simple script that you bind to a hotkey. My setup allows me to switch between two separate montiors with the press of a key combination. Here is a simply [AutoHotKey](https://www.autohotkey.com/) script I put together:

```
#q::
    toggle += 1 ; This increments toggle state (so values after execution of this line will be one of 0,1,2)
    if (toggle = 0)
    {
                Run DisplaySwitch.exe /external
    }
    else if (toggle = 1)
    {
        Run DisplaySwitch.exe /internal
        toggle :=  -1 ; set to -1 so on next run it will end up being 0
    }
Return

sleep 1000

Send ^+{A}
Return
```

So each time I press <kbd>WIN</kbd>+<kbd>Q</kbd> my primary monitor is switched from one device to the other.

You could simply modify this script to use `/external` for one or `/internal` (depending on which monitor the LG is). I would play around with the GUI first, or simply send some basic commands first to get a feel for how it works. Once setup, it's a breeze to switch from one to the other.